# Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'

Tags: c#, xaml

i getting an error in my debug window i have tryed to see if i could make a converter with

```
namespace Omini_Tires_And_rims
{
    public class NullImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

<Image Source="{Binding Path=Billed, Converter={StaticResource nullImageConverter}}"/>
```

but when i put

```
<local:NullImageConverter x:Key="nullImageConverter"/>
```

in to my `windows.ressoruces` i getting

> The type 'local:NullImageConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built

Comment: Have you defined `xmlns:local` in your xaml? You should have the line `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Omini_Tires_And_rims"` in the the user control/page/window definition or you can include it directly in the definition of the converter: `<local:NullImageConverter xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Omini_Tires_And_rims" x:Key="nullImageConverter"/>

Comment: yes `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:omini_dækberegner"`

Comment: That's a different namespace to your converter's. You'll need to create a second alias.

Comment: the namespace is `Omini_Tires_And_rims` not `omini_dækberegner`

Comment: arh i see thats why :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `local` definition doesn't match the namespace of the converter.

You say you've got the following:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:omini_dækberegner"
```

but "omini_dækberegner" is not "Omini_Tires_And_rims".

So you'll either have to change the namespace in the converter class to "omini_dækberegner" or use a different name in your xaml:

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Omini_Tires_And_rims"
```

which you can then use:

```
<converter:NullImageConverter x:Key="nullImageConverter"/>
```

Comment: thats worked  and fixed the error which caused some performance issue on loading the pics